# Showing index() of div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of .post divs that receieve the class of .displayOnly when a user wants to only look at stories with that tag. What I want to do is display a message for each post with the class of ".displayOnly" that I'm showing which displays the index number + 1 within a message. The idea is that the message will say something to the affect of "Displaying 1 of 3," "Displaying 2 of 3" and so on. I've tried using the index() function for this but I keep getting the same result for each message which is "Displaying 1 of 3."

I've included my code below. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

```
$('h4').click(function () {
    var numItems = $('.displayOnly').length;
    var currentItem = $('.displayOnly').index() + 1;

    if ($('.displayOnly').length > 0) {
        $("p.itemCount").css('cssText', 'display:block;');
        $("p.itemCount").append("Displaying " + currentItem + " of " + numItems + ".");

    } else {
        $("p.itemCount").css('cssText', 'display:none;');
        $("p.itemCount").empty();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE: Here is a sample of the html the script is referencing. If it's able to determine length() I'm not sure why index(this) isn't working.**

```html
<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
<p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:17 PM EST</p> 
<h1>Urban Refuges Make it Easier for All People to Get their ‘Nature Fix’</h1>
<p>Debbie Pike is the Visitors Services Manager for Northern New Mexico National Wildlife Refuge Complex (<a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/las_vegas/" target="_blank">Las Vegas</a>, <a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/rio_mora/" target="_blank">Rio Mora</a> and <a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/maxwell/" target="_blank">Maxwell</a> National Wildlife Refuges).  “I work with a ‘high energy’ Friends group that&#8230;<a href="http://www.fws.gov/news/blog/index.cfm/2015/1/16/Urban-Refuges-Make-it-Easier-for-All-People-to-Get-their-Nature-Fix" target="_blank">Read more here&#160;&#187;</a>   <br/></p> <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111992041452/urban-refuges-make-it-easier-for-all-people-to-get">
</a><br />
<h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
<p class="itemCount"></p>
<div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<hr />
</div>

<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
<p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:12 PM EST</p> 
<h1>Connection with Nature Can Happen Anywhere, Even in a City</h1>
<p>Georgia Basso is a wildlife biologist  in our <a href="http://www.fws.gov/northeast/ecologicalservices/coastal.html" target="_blank">Coastal Program</a> and the Service’s liaison to the <a href="http://longislandsoundstudy.net/" target="_blank">Long Island Sound Study</a>, an EPA National Estuary Program to restore and protect&#8230;<a href="http://www.fws.gov/news/blog/index.cfm/2015/1/12/Connection-with-Nature-Can-Happen-Anywhere-Even-in-a-City" target="_blank">Read more here&#160;&#187; </a><br/></p> <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991702182/connection-with-nature-can-happen-anywhere-even">
</a><br />
<h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
<p class="itemCount"></p>
<div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<hr />
</div>

<div class="post ">
<p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:06 PM EST</p> 
<h1>Secretary Talking about the Urban Wildlife Refuge Program</h1>
<figure class="tmblr-embed" data-provider="youtube" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304" data-url="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6PaoZViLBPc%26list%3DUUMqPAPfBGsDMs2UiD-5Tbbg"><iframe width="500" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6PaoZViLBPc?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></figure> <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991188777/secretary-talking-about-the-urban-wildlife-refuge">
</a><br />
<h4># &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
<p class="itemCount"></p>
<div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<hr />
</div>

<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
<p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:05 PM EST</p> 
<h1>14 URBAN WILDLIFE REFUGE PARTNERSHIPS</h1>
<p>From Albuquerque to Yonkers and many cities in between, theU.S. Fish and Wildlife Service is spreading its conservation message. <a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuges/RefugeUpdate/NovDec_2014/14_urban.html" target="_blank">Click here to read more&#160;&#187;</a></p> <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991128157/14-urban-wildlife-refuge-partnerships">
</a><br />
<h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
<p class="itemCount"></p>
<div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<hr />
</div>
```

Comment: From jquery docs: `If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.` so `var currentItem = $('.displayOnly').index()+1;` is always 1.

Comment: From the jquery docs..... of .index() in there example they use... $( "div" ).index( this ); Try adding the keyword this between the brackets.

Comment: `$(".displayOnly").index(this) + 1`

Comment: Sorry: "currentItem();" was left over from a different solution I tried when I had defined a function for it previously. I've removed it as you're all correct that it does nothing when called.

Comment: The `displayOnly` class isn't on the `h4` elements, it's on the `div` that contains it.

Comment: Sorry - I'm a bit confused. Yes, the "displayOnly" class is added on to the "post" div that contains the <h4> that is clicked. "displayOnly is also added to all "post" divs that have the matching tag (i.e. urbanwildliferefuges"). This way only the "post" divs that also have "displayOnly" are shown. I just want to count the "displayOnly" divs that appear (which I've done with length) and show message that states the index of the total of "displayOnly" that is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `currentItem` to the index of the element that was clicked on, you're setting it to the index of the first element matching the `.displayOnly` selector. To refer to the target of the event, use `$(this)`. And since the `displayOnly` class is on the containing DIV, use `.closest()` to find it.

```
$(this).closest('div').index('.displayOnly');
```

And since there's an `.itemCount` element in every DIV, you should use `.find()` to select just the one in the same DIV.

```js
$('.displayOnly h4').click(function() {
  var numItems = $('.displayOnly').length;
  var curDiv = $(this).closest('div.displayOnly');
  var currentItem = curDiv.index('.displayOnly') + 1;

  if (numItems > 0) {
    curDiv.find("p.itemCount").show().html("Displaying " + currentItem + " of " + numItems + ".");
  } else {
    curDiv.find("p.itemCount").hide().empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
  <p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:17 PM EST</p>
  <h1>Urban Refuges Make it Easier for All People to Get their ‘Nature Fix’</h1>
  <p>Debbie Pike is the Visitors Services Manager for Northern New Mexico National Wildlife Refuge Complex (<a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/las_vegas/" target="_blank">Las Vegas</a>, <a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/rio_mora/" target="_blank">Rio Mora</a> and
    <a
    href="http://www.fws.gov/refuge/maxwell/" target="_blank">Maxwell</a>National Wildlife Refuges). “I work with a ‘high energy’ Friends group that&#8230;<a href="http://www.fws.gov/news/blog/index.cfm/2015/1/16/Urban-Refuges-Make-it-Easier-for-All-People-to-Get-their-Nature-Fix" target="_blank">Read more here&#160;&#187;</a> 
      <br/>
  </p>
  <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111992041452/urban-refuges-make-it-easier-for-all-people-to-get">
  </a>
  <br />
  <h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
  <p class="itemCount"></p>
  <div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
  <p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:12 PM EST</p>
  <h1>Connection with Nature Can Happen Anywhere, Even in a City</h1>
  <p>Georgia Basso is a wildlife biologist in our <a href="http://www.fws.gov/northeast/ecologicalservices/coastal.html" target="_blank">Coastal Program</a> and the Service’s liaison to the <a href="http://longislandsoundstudy.net/" target="_blank">Long Island Sound Study</a>,
    an EPA National Estuary Program to restore and protect&#8230;<a href="http://www.fws.gov/news/blog/index.cfm/2015/1/12/Connection-with-Nature-Can-Happen-Anywhere-Even-in-a-City" target="_blank">Read more here&#160;&#187; </a>
    <br/>
  </p>
  <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991702182/connection-with-nature-can-happen-anywhere-even">
  </a>
  <br />
  <h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
  <p class="itemCount"></p>
  <div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="post ">
  <p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:06 PM EST</p>
  <h1>Secretary Talking about the Urban Wildlife Refuge Program</h1>
  <figure class="tmblr-embed" data-provider="youtube" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304" data-url="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6PaoZViLBPc%26list%3DUUMqPAPfBGsDMs2UiD-5Tbbg">
    <iframe width="500" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6PaoZViLBPc?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </figure>
  <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991188777/secretary-talking-about-the-urban-wildlife-refuge">
  </a>
  <br />
  <h4># &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
  <p class="itemCount"></p>
  <div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="post urbanwildliferefuges displayOnly">
  <p class="date">Tuesday, Feb 24, 2015 - 6:05 PM EST</p>
  <h1>14 URBAN WILDLIFE REFUGE PARTNERSHIPS</h1>
  <p>From Albuquerque to Yonkers and many cities in between, theU.S. Fish and Wildlife Service is spreading its conservation message. <a href="http://www.fws.gov/refuges/RefugeUpdate/NovDec_2014/14_urban.html" target="_blank">Click here to read more&#160;&#187;</a>
  </p>
  <a href="http://americaswild.tumblr.com/post/111991128157/14-urban-wildlife-refuge-partnerships">
  </a>
  <br />
  <h4>#urbanwildliferefuges &raquo;<br /><span style="font-weight:300; font-style:italic; font-size:.85em !important;">See more like this</span></h4>
  <p class="itemCount"></p>
  <div style="float:none; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: You would probably replace `append` with `html`. Anyhow, that's the variation on your solution I had :)

Comment: I didn't really bother to fix the other likely bugs in his code.

Comment: I've $(this).index('.displayOnly'); as well as $(".displayOnly").index(this) + 1 and I'm receiving the result of "Displaying 0 of 3" for each of the posts. Not sure what I'm missing. I'll include the html this is referencing above.

Comment: See my latest changes. I've merged in your HTML and modified the code to do what I think you want.